# Pyramid app: How can I pass values into my request.route_url?

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

I have this in my views.py file as the view config for my home page:

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']
        body = request.params['body']
        page=Page(name,body)
        DBSession.add(page)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
    return {}
```

Also, here is the form in the edit.pt template:

```
<form action="/view_page" method="post">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="body"/>
    </div>
<label for="stl">Stl</label>
<input name="stl" type="file" value="" />
<input type="submit" name='form.submitted' value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Also in my **init**.py file I have

```
    config.add_route('home_page', '/')
    config.add_route('view_page', '/{pagename}')
```

right now when I submit the form it just tries to go to localhost:6543/view_page. This returns a 404 as there is no view_page resource or route leading to it. Instead I want it to go to localhost:6543/(the name of the page I just created aka the first input box in the form). How can I do this?

Edit: I am worried that something else may be telling it to route to view_page because I even tried changing it to

```
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('front_page',pagename=name))
```

And it still goes to /view_page. There is no route named front_page, so I would at least suspect it to throw an error.

Also, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me where you found the info. I have been looking at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/request.html?highlight=request.route_url#pyramid.request.Request.route_url but can't seem to find use from it.

Edit: should I be using an asset specification instead of a path name? so

```
return HTTPFound(Location=request.route_url('tutorial:templates/view.pt','/{pagename}'))
```

Also, I am working through this article which seems very helpful with the syntax: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#urldispatch-chapter

Comment: Sounds to me like you should just not add a route for it and use the subpath in some way. Traversal may well match your requirements better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your form should submit to "/", ie.

```
<!-- where your home_page route is waiting for the POST -->
<form action="/" method="post">
```

With the prior answers this now looks correct:

```
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page', pagename=name))
```

Comment: how did you know to change the form action to "/"? Does the form action describe the page that the info is put on or the page that is created once the form is submitted?

Comment: The form action is a URL that is sent over HTTP to pyramid on the server and then matched against routes and finally mapped to a view callable.  So to backtrack this process I looked at your view callable, the home_page() function, then at its route via view_config, "home_page".  Once I had the route I looked at your add_route call to determine the url/url pattern for "home_page" which was "/".  So I knew that posting to "/" would match "home_page" route and continue to your home_page() function (view callable).

Answer (score 0):

from the [link](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/request.html?highlight=request.route_url#pyramid.request.Request.route_url) you give
it's should be

```
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
```

when you had add this route

```
    config.add_route('view_page', '/{pagename}')
```

and set the variable name before

```
    name= request.params['name']
```

Comment: This didn't work it does exactly the same thing. I have updated the question to match that code though because thats what I think should work. Could anything else be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that it's `location` not `Location` as the argument to `HTTPFound`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't fix the issue though you are right