# How can I pass parameters from one view to another

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

I can't get this to work: I navigate to the page I want, but I'm doing something wrong with the variables it seems.

**views.py**:

```
@view_config(http_cache=1,route_name='hoofdpagina', renderer='templates/hoofdpagina.pt')
def hoofdpagina(request):
page = DBSession.query(MyModel) #.filter_by(id='1').all()

if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
    name= request.params['name']
    page2=Page(name)
    DBSession.add(page2)
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
return dict(page=page) 


@view_config(route_name='diagnose', renderer='templates/diagnose.pt')
def diagnose(request):
    return request
    kak = ['test1','test2','test3t']
    content = {"test1","test2","test3"}
    return {'content' :content, 'test' :kak}
```

**hoofdpagina.pt**:

```
<form class="span12" action="/diagnose" method="POST"> 
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th>D Nr.</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Patient</th>
                <th>Prior</th>                              
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr tal:repeat="Page page" >

                <td tal:content="Page.dosiernummer"></td>
                <td tal:content="Page.dosiernummer"></td>                                
                <td tal:content="Page.datum"></td>  
                <td tal:content="Page.naamPatient"></td> 
                <td tal:content="Page.prioriteit"></td>    
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> 

<form action="/diagnose" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="form.submitted" ></input>
    <label name="name">et werkt slet</label>
</form>
```

I can show all the variables of page in my table. But when I press the submit button I can't get the content of the "name" label to my diagnose page. I don't know how I can show the value.

**ps**: question is based on this post: [Pyramid app: How can I pass values into my request.route_url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634444/pyramid-app-how-can-i-pass-values-into-my-request-route-url/15210134#15210134)

Comment: Contents of label-elements are not sent when you submit a form.

Comment: It seems you are not only new to pyramid, but to HTML/HTTP also

Comment: Fix the indentation please.

Comment: k i fixed my problems, I just didn't have enough knowledge about how pyramid works. I just read all the documentation on pyramid in the cookboock (The Pyramid Web Application Development Framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a sollution is working with url dispatching like this:

**_*init*_.py:**

```
config.add_route('diagnose1', '/diagnose1/{dosierid}')
```

**views.py**

```
@view_config(route_name='diagnose1', renderer='templates/diagnose.pt')
def diagnose1(request):
    tabeldata=''
    dosierid = request.matchdict['dosierid']
```

now you have your id from one view to another.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  you'd need an input of some sort:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="et werkt slet">
```

or type="hidden" if you don't want it displayed.

I'm still learning Pyramid as well, but I also wonder if from your code that the submit action is going to post to def hoofdpagina anyway.  I think you might have to move your POST handling to:

```
@view_config(route_name='diagnose', renderer='templates/diagnose.pt')
def diagnose(request):
if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
    name= request.params['name']
    page2=Page(name)
    DBSession.add(page2)
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the init.py you have to add url dispatching (config.add_route).
Your can get the data out of the url and pass on to another page like this.